# DeadLink exception from Python2 to Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib2

I found this code written in Python 2.7 to bypass a deadlink while reading a list of urls and retrieving their content:

```
for i in xrange(lines):
    try:
        t = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(lines[i]))
        deadlinkfound = False
    except:
        deadlinkfound = True
    if not(deadlinkfound):
        urllib.urlretrieve(lines[i], "Images/imag" + "-%s" % i)
```

It worked fine in Python2 but I can't find the equivalent in Python3 because of the urllib2 merging.

Comment: So why can't [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) serve this need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the exact same thing with `urllib.request` here. *Don't* catch every conceivable exception, only catch what is reasonably going to be thrown:

```
from urllib import request, error
from http.client import HTTPException

for i, url in enumerate(lines):
    try:
        t = request.urlopen(request.Request(url, method='HEAD'))
    except (HTTPException, error.HTTPError):
        continue
    request.urlretrieve(url, 'Images/imag-{}'.format(i))
```

This code does the same, but more efficiently.